# How to get all records(related and non related) of Laravel belongsTo relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, belongs-to

How can I get all the records from the relationship? I mean not only the related records, but also the rest.

Let's say I have a post which belongs to some category. If I want to change the category of this post I need a list of all available categories. Can I get this list from the relationship?

The **Post** model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

The **Category** model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

In the **PostsController** I tried:

```
$postModel->category->find('all'); // Returns null
$postModel->category->all(); // Returns only the related categories
```

I know I can simply use the Category model in the PostsController, but I prefer to do it using the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel you must use the relationship to get to the other model you could try:

```
$categories = $post->category()->getRelated()->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked. You said there is no reason to use the relationship, but is it OK to use multiple models in the controller?

Comment: I updated the answer to use a different method, I think it should be `getRelated()` instead of `getChild()` .. check if that is still correct

Comment: there is no 1 to 1 between controller and models ... think of things as dealing with resources and units of work, what ever you need to use you need to use

Comment: The main reason to use relationships is to get eager loading, knowing whether or not you actually need eager loading is a rather technical discussion. It solves the N+1 problem for queries but, also if you are doing simple things it is kind of like bringing an AR-15 to a knife fight... just unnecessary.